# Java: Simple regex question, complete words

Tags: java, regex

i need a Regex to do this ( catch only real words ):

Inputstring:

```
hello,sdfsdf.....yahoo@email.com
```

Process:

```
 String theMagicRegEx = "?????";
 String[] arrayvar = asdf.split(theMagicRegEx);
```

Output (arrayvar) should be this:

```
hello
sdfsdf
yahoo
email
com
```

Question: What is the value of theMagicRegEx?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `str.split("[\\W\\d_]+");`.

This will leave only word characters, no numbers or underscore.

Answer (score 5):

Try `\W+` (non-word characters)

Comment: ...but be aware that numbers and underscore (_) are also part of `\w` and therefore there won't be a split in `good4you`, for example.

Comment: How would i integrate these characters aswell?

Comment: See Tim's answer if you want numbers and underscore to be considered as separators as well

Answer (score 3):

So you want to split the string on non-word characters? There you have the `\W` for. Also see the [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) API for an overview of regex operators.

```
String[] arrayvar = asdf.split("\\W+");
```